Is there any way to capture whole Wikipedia links
I'm developing a tool for Wikipedia that fixes mistakes and replaces incorrect words in the text of Urdu language. Right now, it's replacing words everywhere, even in links and templates. But I want to avoid changing links and templates to prevent breaking them. I've tried different ways to do this, but it's not working. How can I make sure the tool doesn't change any text inside double square brackets or double curly braces?
Here's the code for the function that fixes words. It's already skipping text like "[[JavaScript]]" and "{{JavaScript}}", but I need it to skip entire links or those links which includea incorrect words like "[[source codes of JavaScript software]]" and "{{source codes of JavaScript software}}". Specifically, I want the tool to ignore all text inside double square brackets or double curly braces.
async function imla(imlaWords) {
try {
    const pageTitle = mw.config.get('wgTitle');
    let pageContent = await loadPage(pageTitle);
    const originalContent = pageContent;

    // Regex patterns for wiki links and words between curly braces
    const wikiLinkRegex = /\[\[(.*?)(\|.*?)?\]\]/g; // Regex for wiki links
    const curlyBracesRegex = /\{\{(.*?)(\|.*?)?\}\}/g; // Regex for words between curly braces

    imlaWords.forEach(([incorrectWord, correctWord]) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(incorrectWord, 'g');
        pageContent = pageContent.replace(regex, (match) => {
            // Check if the matched word is within square brackets or curly braces
            const isWithinSquareBrackets = wikiLinkRegex.test(match);
            const isWithinCurlyBraces = curlyBracesRegex.test(match);
            if (isWithinSquareBrackets || isWithinCurlyBraces) {
                // If within square brackets or curly braces, don't replace
                return match;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, replace with the correct word
                return correctWord;
            }
        });
    });

    const imlaCorrected = originalContent !== pageContent;

    if (imlaCorrected) {
        // اصلاحات کو صفحہ میں محفوظ کیا جا رہا ہے
        await savePage(pageTitle, pageContent);
        openDiffPage(pageTitle); // اصلاحات کے بعد فرق صفحہ کھولنے کے لیے
    } else {
        // اگر اصلاح کی ضرورت نہ ہو تو
        mw.notify('اِس صفحہ میں اصلاح کی ضرورت محسوس نہیں ہوئی۔');
    }
} catch (error) {
    mw.notify(error.message);
}

}

Don't use regex for this. Parse the wikitext into an AST: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid Then do your replacements only on the parts that you want to affect

Your strategy won't work because your initial regex will only match a word needing to be replaced, which would either be inside or outside of a link/template. There'd be no way to know which it is, especially since your matches won't include any of the {{/[[ separators.
So the way to do this is by finding all text segments that are in between {{/[[ separators, and do not contain any of them inside of it. Luckily, things are made easy by the fact that links/templates can't be nested inside of each other, so we know that there won't be any overlapping links/templates. If we find an opening separator ({{/[[), we know that the exact end of the link/template will be after we find the next closing separator (}}/]]).
So now all matches will be a segment of text not containing any links/templates. We can then separate it into words (likely with another regex or .split()), and replace each word if it needs to be replaced.


let pageContent = 'sagf sag [[sa gsagsag]] as gad sdgsg [[sgsg]] sgg hed {{jhssfg sdhj}} he ha sg'

pageContent = pageContent.replace(/(?<=^|\]\]|\}\}).*?(?=\[\[|\{\{|$)/g, nonlink => {
    return nonlink.toUpperCase()
    //return nonlink.replace(incorrectWord, correctWord)
})

console.log(pageContent);



